# How do I stack triangles on top of each other and increasing in size and being perfectly aligned

Tags: python

I am playing around with Python and I want to stack 4 triangles on top of each other but increasing in size where the top of each triangle should be exactly halfway along the baseline of the triangle above.  Below is the code I am using but the triangle above keeps moving to the left and I cannot figure out how to keep it centre.

```py
# Draw 4 triangles increasing in size
from turtle import *

# Draw a triangle
for sides in range (1,4):
    forward(20)
    left(120)

# Move to position for second triangle
penup()
left(120)
forward(20)
right(120)
pendown()

# Draw second triangle
for sides in range (1,4):
    forward(40)
    left(120)

# Move to position for third triangle
penup()
left(120)
forward(40)
right(120)
pendown()

# Draw third triangle
for sides in range (1,4):
    forward(60)
    left(120)

# Move to position for fourth triangle
penup()
left(120)
forward(60)
right(120)
pendown()

# Draw fourth triangle
for sides in range (1,4):
    forward(80)
    left(120)
```

Comment: In order for this to work with your method, your right triangle size needs to double on every iteration. That's why your first iteration works. So it should be `20`, `40`, `80`, `160` rather than `20`, `40`, `60`, `80`.

Comment: That did work but I want the length of each triangle to be 20, 40, 60, 80 and not double in size.  The move position code needs amending but I don't know what to that's the issue.  The first and second sizes of triangle are correct, but I want the third to be 60 units and the fourth 80 units.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to adjust the way you are calculating the starting point of each triangle.

Your current method will only work for right triangles that double in size.

The easy method is to retrace your steps to the apex of your just drawn triangle, turn left 120 degrees, and move forward half the distance of your next triangle.

Modifying your code to do so would look like this.

```
# Draw 4 triangles increasing in size
from turtle import *

# Draw a triangle
for sides in range (1,4):
    forward(20)
    left(120)

# Move to position for second triangle
penup()
# point left towards the apex
left(60)
# move to the apex
forward(20)
# turn left in order to move horizontally
left(120)
# move along the next base half the distance of the next triangle(center it)
forward(20)
# turn back around in order to start drawing the next triangle
left(180)
pendown()

# Draw second triangle
for sides in range (1,4):
    forward(40)
    left(120)

# Move to position for third triangle
penup()
left(60)
forward(40)
left(120)
forward(30)
right(180)
pendown()

# Draw third triangle
for sides in range (1,4):
    forward(60)
    left(120)

# Move to position for fourth triangle
penup()
left(60)
forward(60)
left(120)
forward(40)
right(180)
pendown()

# Draw fourth triangle
for sides in range (1,4):
    forward(80)
    left(120)
```

However, you have a lot of duplicated code here. By placing the repeatable parts in functions and utilizing a loop you can condense it quite a bit.

```
# Draw 4 triangles increasing in size
from turtle import *

def draw_triangle(size):
    for _ in range(3):
        forward(size)
        left(120)

def move_to_next_position(previous_size, next_size):
    penup()
    left(60)
    forward(previous_size)
    left(120)
    forward(next_size // 2)
    left(180)
    pendown()

draw_triangle(20)
for prev, nxt in zip((20, 40, 60), (40, 60, 80)):
    move_to_next_position(prev, nxt)
    draw_triangle(nxt)
```

Answer (score 0):

That was fun :) Thanks for the puzzle.

Here is a more generic version, where you can set the sides and sizes:

```
def radius(side_size, sides):
    return side_size/(2 * math.sin(math.radians(180/sides)))

def apothem(side_size, sides):
    return side_size/(2 * math.tan(math.radians(180/sides)))

def move_to_start(side_size):
    penup()
    left(180)
    forward(size/2)
    right(180)
    pendown()
    
def draw_figure(side_size, sides):
    for side in range(0, sides):
        forward(side_size)
        left(360/sides)
        
def move_to_top_middle(side_size, sides):
    penup()
    angle_to_center = 90 - 180/sides
    left(angle_to_center)
    forward(radius(side_size, sides))    
    right(angle_to_center)
    left(90)
    if SIDES % 2 == 0:
        forward(apothem(size, sides))
    else:
        forward(radius(size, sides)) 
    right(90)    
    pendown()

for size in SIZES:
    move_to_start(size)
    draw_figure(size, SIDES)
    move_to_top_middle(size, SIDES)
```

Outcome with:

```
SIZES = [20, 40, 60, 80]
SIDES = 3
```

[image]

And with:

```
SIZES = [20, 15, 25]
SIDES = 12
```

[image]